# Why is this a problem? : Error: "the researcher is assuming an alpha level below the nominal" (p < 0.05)

Tags: statistical-significance, anova, monte-carlo, f-test

I'm trying to understand an article about significance testing and ANOVA, where Monte Carlo simulations were run. The final sentence of this paragraph (in bold) makes absolutely no sense to me.

> "Type I error is the probability of rejecting a null hypothesis when it is actually true. The robustness of a statistical test can be evaluated via Monte Carlo simulation techniques, and in order to ensure the comparability of results from Monte Carlo studies a standard criterion to assess robustness must be established. Bradley’s (1978) liberal criterion is considered the most appropriate (e.g.,Keselman, Algina, Kowalchuk, & Wolfinger, 1999;Kowalchuk, Keselman, Algina, & Wolfinger, 2004). According to this criterion, a statistical test is considered robust if the empirical Type I error rate is between .025 and .075 for a nominal alpha level of .05. When the rate is above .075 the test is considered liberal, increasing the risk of declaring mean differences that do not exist. **When the rate is below .025 the test is considered conservative, such that the researcher is assuming an alpha level below the nominal**" (Blanca et al., 2018).

**Throughout the article, rates below .025 or above .075 are considered "non-robust."**  Robustness, a binary variable, is what's used in all the chi-squares testing the article talks about. The point of the article to assist researchers in determining whether they can trust their F-test, based on differences in group variance and group sample size.

**My question is**, why is it considered a failure here to have an actual significance level of 0.01 when you did a wide range of simulations at a significance level of 0.05? ***And how is this being attributed to "the researcher?"*** This is simulated data, where the differences in variance and sample size are being adjusted, while maintaining normality.

I'm looking for an explanation of the last sentence in the above paragraph.

Reference: Blanca, M. J., Alarcón, R., Arnau, J., Bono, R., & Bendayan, R. (2018). [Effect of variance ratio on ANOVA robustness: Might 1.5 be the limit?](https://doi.org/10.3758/s13428-017-0918-2) *Behavior Research Methods*, 50(3), 937–962.

(This particular article is open-access through Springer.)

Comment: By analogy, you might as well inquire why it's bad for a manufacturer to send you basketballs when you ordered a crate of footballs.  A test run at a level of 0.01 differs importantly from a test run at a level of 0.05: the risk of false positives is far less.

Comment: Thank you for those comments, but I don't see how they have any bearing on the issue: it's bad to believe a procedure you are using has an intended level of risk but actually has a far different level.  Among other things, this precludes you from using a *more powerful* procedure that meets the intended $\alpha$ level.

Comment: The authors are only testing for Type 1 errors. They are doing simulations against an alpha of .05.  I don't believe they are doing any "runs" at any particular level ("run at a level of 0.01," as you say).  Rather, on a given run, they run ANOVA against a set of samples, and then compare the result to the "real population" data - which is a much larger set which they generated, and determine if the null hypothesis that there is no difference between the means was incorrectly rejected.  -- I don't see anywhere where they are intentionally setting alpha levels.  (Continued...)

Comment: (Continued) They are using randomly generated data, with targeted differences in variance. (And they are holding normality to be satisfied, to isolate for variance differences.)

Comment: Your remark on "intentionally setting alpha levels:" indicates you would benefit from reviewing how hypothesis testing works.  Setting $\alpha$ is the key to the whole procedure.

Comment: Re: "it's bad to believe a procedure you are using has an intended level of risk but actually has a far different level. "  -- So, if I have a hypothesis that something causes a change in the means, test it at .05, and the null is rejected at .009, then I had a BAD test design, because I didn't test it at .01 instead?  What????

Comment: I think you need to read the article.  The are using an alpha of .05.  (Re: "intentionally setting alpha levels") If you believe that isn't the case, please identify the paragraph that says that.

Comment: My understanding is they *want* alpha to be 0.05 and are remarking that when the true test level differs substantially from that, it's a problem.  Since you continue to object to that understanding, I'll have to confess I cannot figure out what you're trying to ask.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me that they would want alpha to be .05.  They are doing simulations to see how variance differences combined with group size differences affect ANOVA validity.  If you get a p of .024 (<.025), and there is a real difference between the means, how is that failure?  ANOVA worked with the criteria.

Comment: @MikeSmith the reason you would not be happy a test having a nominal 0.05 error rate but actually having a 0.01 error rate is that you are probably leaving substantial power on the table. Using such a test would increase the risk of false negatives. Imagine you run the test and you get a p-value of 0.06. You would fail to reject because p > 0.05, but if you were using the *actual* distribution of the p-value rather than the assumed Uniform one, you would probably have p < 0.05 instead.

Comment: @guy why don't you convert your comment (which is spot-on) into an answer. You might also note the increased risk of false-positives when the true rate is much higher than nominal.

Comment: I understand that if the researcher chooses .01, that could be too conservative.  That isn't the question, and the simulations don't involve any actions on the part of "a researcher."  The simulations involve changing the differences in the variances and sample sizes, and then calculating a p-value (F-test), and then comparing that to the truth (the very large simulated dataset the samples were drawn from).  How is a p-value of .024, when the means are really different (so ANOVA still works with these variance and sample sizes), an error on the part of "a researcher?"

Comment: @guy - The authors are very specific in that they are only testing for Type 1 errors, and not false negatives.  So your entire comment is off the point.

Comment: @MikeSmith I think you have a good idea from the comments *why* one cares if the level smaller than it was intended - conservative tests tend to be underpowered (this isn't a mathematical truth, but it tends to be the case). I suspect that if you asked the authors why one avoids using conservative tests, this is the answer they would give, and I doubt you are going to learn much more by carefully scrutinizing their words. If you want to know exactly why they say what they say, you can email them.

Answer (score 1):

The Type I error rate is the probability of rejecting a null hypothesis when it is actually true. For a test with a 0.05 Type I error rate, we should be able to generate many datasets under the null hypothesis, and see that we reject the null 5% of the time. If we see that our Monte Carlo simulation results in the null being rejected only 1% of the time, however, our test is actually more powerful than we thought - only 1% of our rejected nulls are false, not 5%. Conversely, if we reject 10% of our nulls, our test is not as good as assumed, since our empirical Type I error rate is higher than the nominal alpha level of 0.05. The authors suggest here that an "acceptable" window around a nominal 5% Type I error rate is within a true error rate of 2.5% and 7.5%.

A statistical test is not considered "robust" if its empirical Type I error rate does not match up with its stated alpha level - the test isn't doing what it says "on the tin", and is actually rejecting null hypotheses more or less frequently than we'd expect. It's not the worst thing to have a test more powerful than you expect, but it is more conservative and will fail to find true differences more often than you're expecting. If you want a 5% Type I error rate, you shouldn't use a test with a 1% Type I error rate - if you do, you're implicitly tightening your significance threshold. The opposite is even worse, if your test is less powerful than you expect, you might be falsely rejecting nulls more often than you realize - believing a test has a 1% error rate when it's actually 5% can lead to spurious rejections of the null.

Comment: Although you are right, your logic is obscure, because power is not directly related to the type I error rate.  The reason why a low type I error rate implies a lack of power derives from the assumption that you could somehow relax the test so that, while still meeting the nominal type I error rate for all distributions in the null hypothesis, for some distributions in the *alternate* hypothesis it will be more likely to reject the null: *that* is what increased power means.

Comment: My question is: Why is anything being attributed to "a researcher?" There is no statement about the importance of a Type I error vs  Type II error.  What is acceptable in sociological research may not be acceptable in pharmaceutical research.  -- These are Monte Carlo simulations, and the authors are explicit that they are only interested in Type 1 errors.

Comment: @MikeSmith They seem to be referring to a hypothetical researcher who is using a potentially non-robust test. If a researcher uses a test with a nominal 0.05 Type I error rate that *actually* has an empirical Type I error rate of 0.025, they are in fact drawing conclusions at a lower alpha than they stated. This issue is attributable to the researcher's own lack of cognizance about the empirical behavior of the test they're using, and could be fixed by either stating the more conservative empirical rate, or by choosing the empirical rate to match their goal.

Comment: 1) You think a researcher can pull this out of a hat: What is the real p-value associated with the real populations behind my test, given the variance ratio associated with my different sample sizes is X?  I don't. 2) What is an acceptable Type I error rate will depend on the type of research.  Power isn't always the primary focus.

Comment: @whuber "power is not directly related to the type I error rate" I am having a difficult time understanding this comment: the chosen level of $\alpha$ (i.e. the type I error rate) directly affects $\beta$ (i.e. the type II error rate), which one can picture graphically as the fail-to reject region defined by alpha on the distribution under the null corresponding directly to the $\beta$ error region under a true alternative distribution, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Alexis You're not wrong.  I believe the last 80% of my comment is a clarification of what that quotation was intended to mean.  Problematic cases include tests where the test statistic is discrete, some nonparametric tests, and tests with composite null hypotheses.

Answer (score 1):

When you declare $\alpha = 0.05$, you are saying that you are okay with a type $1$ error rate of $5\%$.

When the realized type 1 error rate is below the nominal, it means that you have a type $1$ error rate less than $5\%$.

While it might sound like great news to be making fewer mistakes, you had already declared that you were okay with making a certain number of mistakes. Consequently, you can raise $\alpha$ until you realize that tolerable error rate of $5\%$.

By raising your $\alpha$-level, you increase your power to detect differences, and, despite the $\alpha>0.05$, your observed type $1$ error rate is at that tolerable limit of $5\%$.

Conversely, if you observe a type $1$ error rate higher than $\alpha$, you are accepting more type $1$ error, which, by setting $\alpha$, you had decided was unacceptable. In order to get back to the acceptable type $1$ error rate, you must lower $\alpha$, and this decreases power to detect differences.

Let's do an `R` example to see how to tune $\alpha$. I will use a Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney U test to examine for a difference in means between $Beta(1/2, 1/2)$ and $N(1/2, 1)$, which have the same mean of $1/2$. The Wilcoxon Mann-Whitney U test is not quite a test of mean equality, but it often gets used that way.

```
set.seed(2021)
alpha <- 0.05
N <- 100
B <- 1000
ps <- rep(NA, B)
for (i in 1:B){
    x <- rnorm(N, 1/2, 1)
    y <- rbeta(N, 1/2, 1/2)
    ps[i] <- wilcox.test(x, y)$p.value
}
ecdf(ps)(alpha) # 0.076
```

That final line says that the type $1$ error rate of this test is $7.6\%$, when you had decided that you wanted an error rate of $5\%$. To determine the $\alpha$ we should use to get the desired $5\%$ type $1$ error rate, use the `quantile` function.

```
quantile(ps, 0.05) # 0.0336058281017968
```

So we should pick $\alpha=0.0336$ to get the desired type $1$ error rate.

```
set.seed(2021)
alpha <- 0.0336
N <- 100
B <- 1000
ps <- rep(NA, B)
for (i in 1:B){
    x <- rnorm(N, 1/2, 1)
    y <- rbeta(N, 1/2, 1/2)
    ps[i] <- wilcox.test(x, y)$p.value
}
ecdf(ps)(alpha) # 0.05
```

This change in alpha, however, decreases our power to reject a false null hypothesis, such as $Beta(1/2, 1/2)$ and $N(1/3, 1)$.

```
set.seed(2021)
alpha <- 0.0336
N <- 100
B <- 1000
ps <- rep(NA, B)
for (i in 1:B){
    x <- rnorm(N, 1/3, 1)
    y <- rbeta(N, 1/2, 1/2)
    ps[i] <- wilcox.test(x, y)$p.value
}
ecdf(ps)(0.05) # 0.358
ecdf(ps)(0.0336) # 0.295
```

When we have to lower $\alpha$, we lose some power to detect this difference, dropping from $35.8\%$ to $29.5\%$.

**ANALOGY**

The speedometer in my car always gives a speed that is higher than the speed I am traveling. Consequently, if I want to drive on a road with a speed limit of $60$, I should push the speedometer up above $60$. This has the benefit of getting me to my destination sooner than I would if I drove at a speed that resulted in a reading of $60$. However, if my car displays a speed lower than I am traveling, I need to drive at a speed that displays as lower than $60$. Compared to my drive when the speedometer displayed $60$, this will take longer. However, I am traveling $60$, which is the maximum speed allowed before I will get a speeding ticket.

Answer (score -2):

The statement in the article, "the researcher is assuming an alpha level below the nominal," **is invalid**. (Assuming the statement was valid was causing me to have problems interpreting the article.)

Nothing is being said about the importance of a Type I error vs. a Type II error. What is acceptable in sociological research may not be acceptable in pharmaceutical research.  The power of a test is a research choice, but again, that isn't addressed in the article.

Initially, I thought the author was only reporting robust vs. non-robust results in the tables, and given that p-values below .025 were treated as failures (non-robust), just like values above .075 are, it appeared the tables would be **practically worthless** to people interested in knowing how variance and sample size differences could cause Type I errors - **which is what the article says the article is about.**

**Fortunately, there are tables in the Appendix which show the actual F-test values for all the scenarios, which will be very useful.** You can match up your ANOVA scenario, and watch how the F-test results are affected by increases in the variance ratio.

Comment: I need to get back to what I was doing.  I've marked my calendar to come back here in a week and read whatever has been posted on the question and answers.